# Uncaught (in promise): Error: Export of name 'ngForm' not found

Tags: angular, forms, ionic-framework, ngmodel

I am trying to use ngModel to do data binding, however, I get an error ngForm not found. I have already included formsmodule in app.module.ts as you can see below. The error disappears when i remove **#grantAccessForm= "ngForm"** but when i do this and input data in input field and submit, my page refreshes and the refreshed page has params in the url, like this: "http://localhost:8100/signup?name=a&userName=a&email=a@email.com&password=aa&confirm=aa"

I want to be able to do something in the onSubmit() function without the page being refreshed, can someone explain to me what **#grantAccessForm= "ngForm"** this means and why am i getting this error.

> app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginPageComponent } from './login/login-page/login-page.component';
import { SignUpPageComponent } from './login/sign-up-page/sign-up-page.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then( m => m.HomePageModule)
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: LoginPageComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginPageComponent,

    //()=> import('./login/login-page/login-page.component').then(m=> m.LoginPageComponent)
  },
  {
    path: 'signup',
    component: SignUpPageComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

> app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(), 
    AppRoutingModule, 
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  exports:[],

  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

> sign-up-page.component.html

```
</ion-content>
  <form #grantAccessForm= "ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(grantAccessForm)">
    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row justify-content-center>
        <ion-col align-self-center size-md="6" size-lg="5" size-xs="12">
          <div  class="centerText">
            <h3>Create your account!</h3>
          </div>
          <div padding>

            <ion-item>
              <ion-input  name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" [(ngMode)]="dataModel.name"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>

            <ion-item>
              <ion-input  name="userName" type="text" placeholder="Username"  [(ngModel)]="dataModel.username"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>

            <ion-item>
              <ion-input name="email" type="email" placeholder="your@email.com"  [(ngModel)]="dataModel.email"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>

            <ion-item>
              <ion-input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password"  [(ngModel)]="dataModel.password"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>

            <ion-item>
              <ion-input name="confirm" type="password" placeholder="Password again"  [(ngModel)]="dataModel.passwordAgain"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
          </div>
          <div padding>
            <ion-button  size="large" type="submit" expand="block" >Register</ion-button>
          </div>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
  </form>
</ion-content>
```

> sign-up-page.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms'; 
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sign-up-page',
  templateUrl: './sign-up-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sign-up-page.component.scss'],
})
export class SignUpPageComponent implements OnInit { 

// Import ViewChild
@ViewChild('grantAccessForm', {static: false}) grantAccessForm: NgForm;
dataModel: any = {}; // Your data model


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {}

  onSubmit(form) {
    console.log(form);
    
  }

}
```

Comment: This also happens when you apply the directive to an input or another form control. If input, try `ngModel` instead.

Answer (score 14):

i had the same issue so you need to add you singUpComponent in the app.module.ts

Comment: More info here: [NG0301](https://angular.io/errors/NG0301)

Answer (score 13):

I faced the similar issue, in my case I was trying to open that component from a ModalController.

**The solution is in app.module.ts under imports you need to add FormsModule & you need to add the component in declarations array.**

The below mentioned app.module.ts should work

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {SignUpPageComponent} from './sign-up-page.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent,SignUpPageComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(), 
    AppRoutingModule, 
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  exports:[],

  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 11):

I am facing this issue while using Reactive Forms in the component. I found this error in unit test case execution.

Simple solution is add `ReactiveFormsModule` in the `imports` section.

```
beforeEach(async () => {
  await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [ YourComponent ],
    imports: [AppRoutingModule,ReactiveFormsModule],
    providers: [ AuthService],
  })
  .compileComponents();
});
```

This will solve your issue.

Comment: In my case I needed FormsModule, but your answer hinted me in the right direction

Answer (score 4):

Add FormsModule in app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Same Issue I have faced for below step it's work for me**

- import FormsModule for app module and working current module from both places'
- import ngForm in you ts file
  then do the below steps

1. terminate console
2. run npm install
3. run server again

Answer (score 1):

I terminated the server. executed the  npm install command and tried once again. Got the issue resolved.

Answer (score 1):

FormsModule is imported in your app.module.ts file, it is ok.

After putting the "ngForm" directive:

https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm#listening-for-form-submission

According to the sample template in the link, you have to put **"ngModel"** directive with the template reference variable (*#var*) into all form elements.

I tried and worked for me.

```html
  <form #grantAccessForm= "ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(grantAccessForm)">
    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row justify-content-center>
        <ion-col align-self-center size-md="6" size-lg="5" size-xs="12">
          <div  class="centerText">
            <h3>Create your account!</h3>
          </div>
          <div padding>

            <ion-item>
              <ion-input  name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" [(ngMode)]="dataModel.name" #inputName="ngModel"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>

            <ion-item>
              <ion-input  name="userName" type="text" placeholder="Username"  [(ngModel)]="dataModel.username" #userName="ngModel"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>

            <ion-item>
              <ion-input name="email" type="email" placeholder="your@email.com"  [(ngModel)]="dataModel.email" #inputEmail="ngModel"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>

            <ion-item>
              <ion-input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password"  [(ngModel)]="dataModel.password" #inputPassword="ngModel"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>

            <ion-item>
              <ion-input name="confirm" type="password" placeholder="Password again"  [(ngModel)]="dataModel.passwordAgain" #inputPassword2="ngModel"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
          </div>
          <div padding>
            <ion-button  size="large" type="submit" expand="block" >Register</ion-button>
          </div>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

well i got the same error and manage to fix it. So first if you separated the modules or created an extra module or in `app.modulets.ts` file you need to add your component to declarations and import imports.
Exp:
on `createdExtra.module.ts` or `app.modulets.ts` do

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [...
                  componetWithNgForm,
                 ...
                 ],
  imports: [
    ...
    FormsModule
  ]
```

Hope i helped.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. I resolved it by adding the component on which I was using ngForm to the declarations list of app.module.ts.

Answer (score 1):

If you have this error with unit testing: import the FormsModule into your component.spec.ts:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

 beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [YourComponent],
      imports: [FormsModule],
    }).compileComponents();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

1. here you miss spelled ngmodel for dataModel.name.
2. Change ion-button html given in answer.

**sign-up-page.component.html**

```
<ion-content padding>
  <h2>Welcome to Ionic!</h2>
  <form #grantAccessForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(grantAccessForm)">
    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row justify-content-center>
        <ion-col align-self-center size-md="6" size-lg="5" size-xs="12">
          <div  class="centerText">
            <h3>Create your account!</h3>
          </div>
          <div padding>

            <ion-item>
              **<!-- Here you miss spelled ngModel -->**
              <ion-input  name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" [(ngModel)]="dataModel.name"></ion-input> 

            </ion-item>

            <ion-item>
              <ion-input  name="userName" type="text" placeholder="Username"  [(ngModel)]="dataModel.username"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>

            <ion-item>
              <ion-input name="email" type="email" placeholder="your@email.com"  [(ngModel)]="dataModel.email"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>

            <ion-item>
              <ion-input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password"  [(ngModel)]="dataModel.password"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>

            <ion-item>
              <ion-input name="confirm" type="password" placeholder="Password again"  [(ngModel)]="dataModel.passwordAgain"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
          </div>
          <div padding> 
            **<!-- Here change button html -->**
            <button ion-button  size="large" type="submit" expand="block" >Register</button>
          </div>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
  </form>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Here is working demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-exbybt

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error, my problem was the the module that holds my form component was lazy loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue in a component that is part of a lazy loaded module. Though I imported FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule into my module and added routing to that component, I forgot to add the component in the declarations. Adding the component there fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone faces similar problem... Getting the error `Error: Export of name 'ngForm' not found` even if `FormsModule` is imported correctly in your own module

This can happen as well if your form declaration is on a; say; a `div` instead of a `form` element.

Prefer

```
    <form #myForm="ngForm"></form>
```

than

```
    <div #myForm="ngForm"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue resolved by the following **First way**.

I was call one Common component(Popup-component) from two different modules like one is patient module and another is doctor module ,
And i was import the common "Popup-component" in patient module but was not import in doctor module.

So that was the problem when i call the common "Popup-component" from doctor module it generate error, because it was not import in doctor module

**ERROR Error: Export of name 'ngForm' not found**

So first you need to check you have imported the component in that module from where you calling it.
..........................

**Second way**

i just import the common "Popup-component" in main app.module.ts and then remove from patient and doctor module .

It also worked for me
I think the second way is best.

try this i hope your problem will be solved

Answer (score 0):

For me terminating the server and restarting it solved the issue.

Its funny when sometimes Angular also behaves like Microsoft -- don't do anything, just restart and things start working...

Answer (score 0):

In the following code, this problem is related to the "role" attribute:

```html
<!-- Wrong -->
<form role="form" (ngSubmit)="save(userForm.value)" userForm="ngForm"></form>
```

```html
<!-- Correct -->
<form (ngSubmit)="save(userForm.value)" #userForm="ngForm"></form>
```

Comment: Can you provide more information on what your code does? Also providing information such as what the differences are between the two blocks  of code will result in a better quality answer.

Answer (score 0):

**WORKING SOLUTION ON THIS ISSUE:**

I was having the same problem, to fix this issue you can import `formsModule` to `app.module.ts` or directly on the component's `.module.ts` file.

The most important thing that nobody say's is YOU MUST NEED to import the component you created on `app.module.ts` file if you don't do then it will won't work and your `ngForm` won't be detected

So make sure you imported your component Module to `app.module.ts`. This way I could solve the issues. and cost me a few hours for that investigation, which nobody said.

Answer (score -1):

Hard reset to the application url resolved my error

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).